# Dynamically Creating ChkBox on click with Different name and Value Giving "NaN" using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

i am trying to create chkbox on click with different name and value and then alerting its value resulting in error "NaN" my script is here,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var k=0,j=0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
            var field = $("#field").val();
         k+=1;
            var newRow1="<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: large; color: #212121;' height='35px'>from"
            +DDL_fromProfession +" to "+DDL_ToProfession +"</td></tr>"
            +"<tr><td align='center' style='font-size:large;color:#212121;' height'35px'>"
            +"<input type='checkbox' name='chkbx_CurrPro'"+k+"'' value='"+k+"'>I currently work here</input>";
            alert(k);
            var chkvalue = parseInt($(":checkbox[name='chkbx_CurrPro'"+k+"'']").val()) + 1;
            alert(chkvalue);                
            var checkBoxes = $("input[name=" + chkbx_CurrPro + "]");
              $.each(checkBoxes, function() {
            if ($(this).attr('checked')){
                //do stuff
            }
            });                        
            var input = "<input name='parameters' id='field' type='text' />";
            var input1="<input name='parametersCompany' id='field' type='text'/>"
            var newRow = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: x-large; color: #212121;' height='35px'>" 
            + input + " at " +input1 +"</td></tr>";
            $('#controls').append(newRow);
            $('#controls').append(newRow1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

i wanna crete chkbox like,

```
name = chkbx_CurrPro0 , value = 0
name = chkbx_CurrPro1 , value = 1
name = chkbx_CurrPro2 , value = 2
             .
             .
             .
```

then i am printing its value resulting in NaN error ?? Hopes for your suggestion
one more thing i wanna do after creating dynamicaally chkbox it will get value of only marked chk box ,

my code here,

```
  var checkBoxes = $("input[name=" + chkbx_CurrPro + "]");
                  $.each(checkBoxes, function() {
                if ($(this).attr('checked')){
                    //do stuff
                }
                });
```

but check all chkbox created at run time

Hopes for Suggestions

Thanks

Comment: are you calling jQuery function after `append` or before `append`?

Comment: on click it append call this query

Answer (score 0):

```
        var chkvalue = parseInt($(":checkbox[name='chkbx_CurrPro'"+k+"'']").val()) + 1;
```

I think you have some issues with the quotes here. Try this...

```
        var chkvalue = parseInt($(":checkbox[name='chkbx_CurrPro"+k+"']").val()) + 1;
```

EDIT: Looks like youhave the same issue here...

```
"<input type='checkbox' name='chkbx_CurrPro'"+k+"'' value='"+k+"'>
```

This will try to make the name chkbx_CurrPro'1' but that is not valid. This should instead be...

```
"<input type='checkbox' name='chkbx_CurrPro"+k+"' value='"+k+"'>
```

Edited Again :
I see another issue here, you are trying to get the value of the checkbox before the checkbox has actually been added to the dom. You have added it to the string, but that is just a string of text when you call parseInt, not a part of the page. Move the parseInt line to below your append lines, near the bottom.